# How to create a popup window programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gridlayout, android-popupwindow

I have made Activity which will popup on click of button. I have to add listener on Image Button. I have made the design in XMl but I want to design programmatically.

This is my image of xml design.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PopupMenu">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageOnlineIcon"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/olnine_user"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserName"
            android:layout_width="201dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="Shyam"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageVideoIcon"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/videonline" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageMuteIcon"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/muted" />
    </GridLayout>
    <View style="@style/Divider"/>
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageOnlineIcon1"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/olnine_user" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserName1"
            android:layout_width="201dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="Samir"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageVideoIcon1"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/videonline" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageMuteIcon1"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/muted" />
    </GridLayout>
    <View style="@style/Divider"/>
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageOnlineIcon2"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/olnine_user" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserName2"
            android:layout_width="201dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="Vivek"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageVideoIcon2"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/videonline" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageMuteIcon2"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/muted" />
    </GridLayout>
    <View style="@style/Divider"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have to create the same design in java programatically. And Add the listener in Image Button so that i can handle the button.

Comment: `I want to design programmatically` what does this mean? Do you want to create all the views with Java code? Why? Also what exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you asking how to recreate that xml layout through Java/Kotlin code or are you asking how to create a Popup Window? By Popup Window, do you mean a dialog?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko. yes, i want to create all the views with java code.

Comment: Ok, and now what is a problem for you to do that?

Comment: @Jackey. Leave about the popup. Simply create the views by the java code. It means you have to convert the xml file into java. As you can see in xml file, there is imagebutton, so that you have to add listener for perform the action.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko. As you can see that , there are three gridlayout. and each gridlayout have four views. Views are imageview, textview and two image button. I have to add listener on imagebutton. So i have to do all these through java code. There may be 5 gridlayout and thier views. i will create dynamically all these.

Comment: you just do `GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(..); ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(..); ib.setOnClickListener(..); gl.addView(ib);`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Now i am trying to convert whole xml file into java. I will upload the code after completion.

Comment: I don't know the way to *convert* it except creating it like I showed above manually. I don't think such a way exists

Comment: Also what is the reason that you don't want to use XML, and want to create it in Java?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I am creating video conferencing meeting app. In one meeting there may be 3 users, so it will create 3 gridlayout and their views.  In another meeting there may be 10 users so it will create 10 gridlayout and their views. So i want this at run time.

Comment: You can just dynamically inflate an XML into a view. Also if you want dynamical similar views amount, you may want to use RecyclerView (ListView)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you told about AlertDialog
You can try to write this method:

```
public void entre () {

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Something");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //what you need to do after click "OK"
        }

    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //what you need to do after click "Cancel"
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

And add it in onClickListner:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    entre ();
}
```

You will get popup window with title "Something" and with two buttons: "Ok" and "Cancel"

Comment: As you can see that , there are three gridlayout. and each gridlayout have four views. Views are imageview, textview and two image button. I have to add listener on imagebutton. So i have to do all these through java code. There may be 5 gridlayout and thier views. i will create dynamically all these.